# TabList control not displaying correctly

Tags: vb6, tabs

I have a `TabList` control on a form that derives from `COMCTL32.OCX`.

On development machines it displays fine, but on clean VMs of XP and Win7 one of the tabs comes up in strange colours.

What could be the problem?

EDIT: I have discovered that the problem is related to Themes. In XP when I change from default theme to "Windows Classic" the problem disappears.  How can I make this control properly colour itself taking into account changes in Themes?  The only thing I can find is this discussion: [Common Controls Tab Control Defects when themed](http://www.adras.com/Common-Controls-Tab-Control-Defects-when-themed.t5475-53-1.html)

Comment: VB6 is somehow dead! I'd been working with it for many years but never such these problems happened to me. Can you show an image or some more details?

Comment: I'll have to describe it in words because I don't want to reveal the design of the app. Basically it is painting a darker colour for all the blank space in the tab and then painting the correct colour for any inner frames and controls.

Comment: BTW, did you use a manifest file to change the program's look? I don't know what the problem is really because I'd never saw anything like this.

Comment: No manifest file. It is colouring the control incorrectly when in certain themes.

Comment: Sorry mate! I can't really grasp. Maybe it's a question eligible for bounty but I think nobody comes to answer for `VB6`. I don't know, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: How do you "derive" controls in VB6?

Comment: "Derive" means to "come from". Are you saying that the `TabList` control does not come from `COMCTL32.OCX`?

Comment: It turned out that the offending tab actually had a different colour code for `BackColor` than the other tabs. This was only showing as a different colour however in certain themes.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never observed such behaviour I would hazard a guess that you may be able to resolve the problem by using one of the following approaches:

Create a manifest file with the content below. Name the file to match your project EXE name with a .manfest extension. Eg. Project1.exe.manifest. Place the manifest file in the same location as your executable and run it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" processorArchitecture="*" version="6.0.0.0" name="mash"/>
<description>Enter your Description Here</description>
<dependency>
   <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
           type="win32"
           name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0"
           language="*"
           processorArchitecture="*"
         publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      />
   </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

Or, you can try adding the following code to the form that contains the MS tabbed control:

```
Private Declare Sub InitCommonControls Lib "comctl32.dll" ()   

Private Sub Form_Initialize()  
    InitCommonControls  
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "No manifest file" do you mean that creating a manifest file did not resolve the issue or that the application does not have a manifest file?

Comment: I did not create a manifest file to fix the problem. The application has never had a manifest file. See last comment above on Feb 29 where I wrote: "It turned out that the offending tab actually had a different colour code for BackColor than the other tabs. This was only showing as a different colour however in certain themes."

Comment: I don't need to. The problem was solved by changing the BackColor code on one of the tabs.  A manifest should not be used unless necessary.

Comment: Got it. I couldn't discern from your comment that you resolved your own problem. Excellent.